Gemini Status 500 when requesting cache
I'm receiving this status 500 when trying to cache a large text corpus (~1.8M tokens):
Script:
import vertexai
from vertexai.preview import caching 
from vertexai.generative_models import Part
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

def create_new_gemini_cache(display_name, content, time_to_live):
    try:
        cached_content = caching.CachedContent.create(
            model_name='gemini-1.5-pro-001',
            contents=content,
            ttl=time_to_live
        )
        logging.info(f'#### Content cached')
        return cached_content

    except Exception as e:  
        handle_exception(e) 

# Get creds
gcp_credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(gemini_cred_json, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

# Init project
vertexai.init(project=GCP_PROJECT_ID, location=GCP_REGION, credentials=gcp_credentials)  

# Get content
content = [Part.from_text(<1.8M token text>)] # Assume large text here.

# Define cache ttl
time_to_live = datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)

# Request  gemini cache content
cache_content = create_new_gemini_cache(content, time_to_live)

Error:
#### Error details: { "message": "500 Internal error encountered.", "status_code": null, "traceback": [ "Traceback (most recent call last):", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py\", line 76, in error_remapped_callable", " return callable_(*args, **kwargs)", " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py\", line 1181, in __call__", " return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)", " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py\", line 1006, in _end_unary_response_blocking", " raise _InactiveRpcError(state) # pytype: disable=not-instantiable", " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", "grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:", "\tstatus = StatusCode.INTERNAL", "\tdetails = \"Internal error encountered.\"", "\tdebug_error_string = \"UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.251.33.106:443 {grpc_message:\"Internal error encountered.\", grpc_status:13, created_time:\"2024-09-05T03:51:37.113071157+00:00\"}\"", ">", "", "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:", "", "Traceback (most recent call last):", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/shared/gemini_utils.py\", line 94, in create_new_gemini_cache", " cached_content = caching.CachedContent.create(", " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/vertexai/caching/_caching.py\", line 228, in create", " cached_content_resource = client.create_cached_content(request)", " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/gen_ai_cache_service/client.py\", line 825, in create_cached_content", " response = rpc(", " ^^^^", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py\", line 131, in __call__", " return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)", " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", " File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py\", line 78, in error_remapped_callable", " raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc", "google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Internal error encountered." ] }

Is my request incorrectly setup or is the service down? How do I know moving forward?

EDIT 1:
Tried this example in Google Collab. Still getting status 500. I've now tried with MANY combinations of environment (local, Azure Function, Google Collab) and text length (very short (under the minimum cache), over the minimum, over 1M tokens...all with the same InternalServerError: 500 Internal error encountered. error.
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     75         try:
---> 76             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     77         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

6 frames

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INTERNAL
    details = "Internal error encountered."
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.7.42:443 {created_time:"2024-09-05T16:06:16.178297904+00:00", grpc_status:13, grpc_message:"Internal error encountered."}"
>


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InternalServerError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     76             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     77         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 78             raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
     79 
     80     return error_remapped_callable

InternalServerError: 500 Internal error encountered.


Edit 2:

So far I've tried:

Different environments:

Google Collab: Failed
Azure Function: Failed
Local machine: Failed


Different context lengths:

content # A string of 1M tokens, 1.8M tokens, etc.
content[:100000]
this is a test


Content with and without [] surrounding
Different models:

flash-001 and pro-001


preview and non-preview versions of GenerativeModels library
Posting in StackOverflow, Google Bug Tracker and Google AI Dev Forum.
Different types of text:

My own text
Project Gutenberg text


Text stored in different places:

Azure Blob Storage: Failed
Google Buckets: Failed
Local: Failed


Various versions of text:

Raw: Failed
Cleaned up: Failed # Removed non-ascii chars, removed \n\r, etc.





Can someone else verify they are able to use vertex Context Caching?

Could you please reduce the content and try again once?

I've tried content[:100000] and all variations. No change. Event this example fails: https://github.com/lavinigam-gcp/gemini-assets/blob/main/context_caching.ipynb. If possible, please try this example and see if it works for you. Then I could narrow it down to something on my end.

Good heavenss...

pip uninstall vertexai, google-cloud-aiplatform
pip install vertexai, google-cloud-aiplatform
Now working fine...
Had version 1.64.0 of both vertexai and google-cloud-aiplatform...there is now v1.65.0
Had to uninstall / reinstall both:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
vertexai 1.64.0 requires google-cloud-aiplatform[all]==1.64.0, but you have google-cloud-aiplatform 1.65.0 which is incompatible.

Would be really awesome if the response status code was something more intuitive.
Now I know! Experience!
